# Pandas Pivot causes all values to be NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 12 columns and 900 entries which looks like this:

```
In [1]: df

Out[2]: 

    Id  BestInGen   Ceiling Fitness Floor   Generation  Name    Precision   Runid   SolutionId  Timestamp                Value
0   1   True    2.5 2.416582e+11    0.500   1   H1001Thickness1 0.010   20180214142319  4   2018-02-14 14:28:41.391908  0.500
1   2   False   0.1 2.830500e+11    0.015   1   H6512Diameter8  0.005   20180214142319  3   2018-02-14 14:28:41.423109  0.015
2   3   False   2.5 2.830500e+11    0.500   1   H2201Thickness1 0.010   20180214142319  3   2018-02-14 14:28:41.423109  0.500
3   4   False   0.1 2.830500e+11    0.015   1   H2201Diameter1  0.005   20180214142319  3   2018-02-14 14:28:41.423109  0.015
4   5   False   2.5 2.830500e+11    0.500   1   H2201Thickness2 0.010   20180214142319  3   2018-02-14 14:28:41.423109  0.500
```

I want to pivot this dataframe such that 'Name' is turned into columns, and the rows populated by 'Value'.

Currently I have tried the following:

```
dfPivot = df.pivot(index='Id',columns='Name',values='Value)
```

I thought this would create the results I need, and that has been the case for the other threads ive seen. But in my case the following happens

```
In [3]: dfPivot

Out [4]: 


Name    H1001Diameter1  H1001Diameter10 H1001Diameter12
Id
1       Nan             Nan             Nan
```

And the same continues to the end of the dataframe, all values being Nan. The original datatype is a float64, and there are no Nans in the original data.

Any pointers on how to solve this? Sorry if this is a noob question, or please let me know if you need me to edit my question/example.

Comment: Try printing out more rows. They are not all NaNs, only where there are no corresponding values. From what you posted I get numeric values in select cells.

Comment: When I print out more they all come out as NaN.
If I try `.dropna()` all rows are dropped.

Comment: Once again, with what you posted here, running exact `pivot` code (fixing missing single quote at end), there are some non-NA values. And be careful with `.dropna`. Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), it drops if **any** NAs are present. Pass in `how='all'` and no columns are dropped for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pd.pivot_table(df[['Id', 'Name', 'Value']],
               index='Id',
               columns=['Name'],
               values=['Value'],
               aggfunc=lambda x: x)
```

This assumes that you don't duplicate values. Otherwise, you need to edit the `aggfunc` to do proper aggregation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try what you mentioned everything still comes out as NaN. You mention aggregation, but I would like to avoid that, since I need to use the values as input for something else.